# How to configure IP addresses in cisco packet tracer?

Tags: cisco, ip, wireless, lan

Hello I am working with Cisco packet tracer. I have two laptops connected to a wireless router with IP addresses assigned using DHCP. The router's Internet IP address is `10.1.0.0` and the LAN address is `192.168.0.1`. I have an image below to for visual.
[image]
Here **Wireless Router0** is the one with the IP addresses I specified above. Also on **Router0** I have set the IP address on the port on which **Switch0** is connected to `10.1.0.0`. I want to make a ping request to **PC0** from **Laptop0** . When I do, I get request timeouts, that is 100% packet loss. I want to know also that how would I access **Laptop0** from **PC0**.

Comment: Please update your drawing to include the address of all the router interfaces.  BTW, if you're using a 24-bit mask, 10.1.0.0 is an invalid address.

Comment: .. or any mask longer than /15...

Comment: Updated the picture.

Comment: you should use access point instead wireless router and then set IP address for laptop and computer in the same range and then ping one of them.

Comment: *assigned using DHCP* - where's your DHCP server? The laptops only get a DHCP config accidentally because you've used a wireless router instead of a more reasonable WAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in the current settings they will never Ping each other because every single system   is in different network, to make them ping you need to get all the systems to a single network or dual network connected to a single node. Explaining it Below

First I can see 3 different networks and apipa network, so now go to the settings of the wireless router 0 and turn of the DHCP in the wireless Router0.

next the cable which is coming from switch 0 and plugged in wireless router 0 check if it is plugged in lan port or internet port? i am pretty sure it is plugged in on the internet port so remove it from there and plug it into the lan port of the wireless router 0 (Any Lan port i think its color is yellow hola)

The Above steps will give your laptop an ip of your main network 10.1.0.0 and your router can now ping your router 0 .

next  step (left side cleared now the right side)

now in the Right side its pretty simple your pc's are not getting the ip address from the router 0 so there is a mistake in your DHCP setting so change it if possible or delete it and create a new one. once your pc gets the ip from the DHCP then yes you are coonnected to the network and boom you will get the ping.